# Check if user said ok to beforeunload?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I want to run an AJAX script when a user says "Ok" to a "beforeunload" event. Now I mean beforeunload, and not onbeforeunload (the latter doesn't work for some reason).

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Isn't it too late for running scripts? PS: there are no events you could listen to anyway

Comment: What do you mean too late?

Comment: when "ok" is clicked - the page is already closed. So your scripts don't exist right after the "ok" button is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just listen to the [`unload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/unload) event, which will occur after `beforeunload` if the user proceeded. However, at this point the UI will not be visible to the user anymore and nothing can stop the unloading process. Perhaps you will be able to make your AJAX call, but I'm not sure if callbacks will be executed and/or if it's reliable.

Comment: It's just intended to send a MySQL to remove the user, but thanks!

Comment: Non-asynchronous AJAX calls will still fire in most cases, but it would be better to not rely on unload events for this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to listen to the unload event, but you will probably not be able to complete any AJAX request there.  For security reasons, the browser will abort it.